# What Linq query can I use to return a count of all products by Category?

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following table structure, how can I use a Linq query to return a list of Category names and the total count of products in that category?

```
Category
---------
ID
Name

Product
---------
ID 
IDCategory
Name
```

My ideal, return would be:

```
Clothes 156
Electronics 2149
Utensils 412
```

Etc.

EDIT:
Thanks for the helpful suggestions, I now have this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDatabaseEntities entities = new MyDatabaseEntities();

        var result = from c in entities.Categories
                        join p in entities.Products on c.ID equals p.IDCategory
                        group p by c.Name into g
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = g.Key,
                            Count = g.Count()
                        };

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How exactly can I output what is in the result? During debugging I can view the variables values and it has what I need I just don't know how to show it.

Comment: so you want this in 1 query? in 2 it's quite easy...

Comment: Honestly, I'd like whatever is best not in terms of speed but in terms of clean code. Which is better to maintain and understand. Keep in mind that I'll be using the returned result on a report.

Comment: Stefanvds: Why not one query? What's wrong with `from c in Category join p in Product on c.ID equals p.IDCategory into prods select new { c.Name, count = prods.Count() }` ?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia, what is best in terms of code is almost always best in terms of speed when you are dealing with databases ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from c in Category
join p in Product on c.ID equals p.IDCategory
group p by c.Name into g
select new
{
    Name = g.Key,
    Count = g.Count()
}
```

That will work in any flavor of LINQ, and groups by the Name, rather than the ID of category.

If you are using LINQ to Entities, this may be faster, and groups on ID rather than name:

```
from p in Product
group p by p.Category into g
select new
{
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Count = g.Count()
}
```

Comment: This query is fine. Note, however, that if duplicate c.Name values exist, then they will be grouped together in this query.

Comment: Hi John, I tried the first method and it works great, my only problem is I don't know how to extract the information from the var variable. How can I extract information from the returned result?

Comment: @Sergio: Use this for example: `foreach(var r in results) { Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", r.Name, r.Count); }`

Answer (score 1):

This query ensures that categories with duplicate names are not grouped together.

```
from p in context.Product
group p by p.Category into grp
select new
{
    CategoryName = grp.Key.Name,
    Count = grp.Count()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Linq77()
{
    List<Product> products = GetProductList();

    var categoryCounts =
        from p in products
        group p by p.Category into g
        select new { Category = g.Key, ProductCount = g.Count() };

    ObjectDumper.Write(categoryCounts
}
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747.aspx#countGrouped) for specific LINQ examples.

Comment: What datatype is categoryCounts? How would I extract the resuls from it?

Comment: It is an IEnumerable<T>.  T in this case is an anonymous type because it is defined by the projected select statement (at compile time).

Comment: Since it is IEnumerable<T>, you can iterate it via a foreach loop or another linq expression.