# How to display records from one to many relationship tables?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

```
[Table("Categories")]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {       
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{       
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Above are two tables, I want to display list of categories including the count of products in each category. How can I use it?

Comment: Welcome too [so]. Please read [ask] and consider expanding your question to explain *how you want to use it* and what you've tried so far, eg - do you need to query the database? what Linq-SQL have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: This question already answered in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600940/what-linq-query-can-i-use-to-return-a-count-of-all-products-by-category)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var categoryCounts =
    from p in products
    group p by p.Category into g
    select new { Category = g.Key, ProductCount = g.Count() };
```

[Count of all products by category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600940/what-linq-query-can-i-use-to-return-a-count-of-all-products-by-category?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: so Your question is not many-to-many. it is one-to-many because Categories Table has a ICollection of product and your product table just has a foreign key of Categories table.

Comment: OK, I read too quickly and got deluded by the plural `Categories` (why do people do that?). Anyway, it still isn't necessary to use a grouping. You can simply count Products of each category.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, in the duplicate question + answers and the answer given here, it didn't occur to anyone that you can simply do:

```
var counts = from c in context.Categories
             select new
             {
                 c.CategoryName,
                 ProductCount = c.Products.Count()
             };
```

Comment: And as usual, complexity is mistaken for proficiency.